# D3 Chart: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ordinal' of undefined

Tags: javascript, wordpress, d3.js

I am absolutely new to `D3 charts` and using it for the first time on my WordPress website.

D3 reference inside plugin.php:

```
class Data_Visualizer {
   public function __construct(){
      add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'evd_enqueue_assets' ) );
   }

   function evd_enqueue_assets() {
      // D3 chat script
      wp_enqueue_script( 'd3-chart', 'https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js' );
   }
}

new Essen_Data_Visualizer();
```

I have written the following function which renders the JavaScript required to draw the chart

```
public function evd_unitary_growth_plan_d3_chart( $data_str ) {
        ob_start(); ?>

        <script type="application/json" id="ddata">
            [
                {
                    "letter":"A",
                    "frequency":0.08167
                },
                {
                    "letter":"B",
                    "frequency":0.01492
                },
                {
                    "letter":"C",
                    "frequency":0.02780
                },
                {
                    "letter":"D",
                    "frequency":0.04253
                },
                {
                    "letter":"E",
                    "frequency":0.12702
                },
                {
                    "letter":"F",
                    "frequency":0.02288
                },
                {
                    "letter":"G",
                    "frequency":0.02022
                }
            ]
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
                width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

            var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

            var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([height, 0]);

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom");

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left")
                .tickFormat(formatPercent);

            var tip = d3.tip()
                .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
                .offset([-10, 0])
                .html(function(d) {
                    return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency + "</span>";
                })

            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            svg.call(tip);

            //var data = <?php echo $data_str; ?>
            var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('ddata').innerHTML);

            x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Frequency");

            svg.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
                .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                .on('mouseout', tip.hide)

            function type(d) {
                d.frequency = +d.frequency;
                return d;
            }
        </script>

        <?php return ob_get_clean();
    }
```

The above function is called from another PHP file like this:
echo $dashboard_data->evd_unitary_growth_plan_d3_chart( $json_str );

I am creating `$json_str` (string) before passing the same to the above function. My $json_str looks like this:

```
[{"month": "Apr-19", "points": 3},{"month": "May-19", "points": 3},{"month": "Jun-19", "points": 5},{"month": "Jul-19", "points": 7},{"month": "Aug-19", "points": 6},{"month": "Sep-19", "points": 4},{"month": "Oct-19", "points": 23},{"month": "Nov-19", "points": 7},{"month": "Dec-19", "points": 7}]
```

But for testing, I am not using this data. Rather using a static JSON to see whether the chart actually renders.

I copied the above code from http://jsfiddle.net/andrewpatt24/jo1bfbpu/ but when running the page I am getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ordinal' of undefined

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I changed D3 reference from `v4` to `v3` (`https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js`) and the `ordinal` error is gone. However I have to get rid of all `tip` in the code even

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'd3-tip', 'http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js' );
```

is referenced.

But even after that the chart is not rendering at all.

```
<div class="chart-display-area" id="ecbg_unitary"></div>

var svg = d3.select("ecbg_unitary").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Nothing gets rendered. When I replace `ecbg_unitary` with `body`, only two thick axes are coming up and nothing else. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: There is no `D3 Charts`, D3 is not a charting tool. Regarding your problem, the issue is quite simple: your code uses D3 v3, but you're referencing D3 v4.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I am actually checking using v3 and v4. Even when I am trying to draw a simple chart using this https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/bdf28027e0ce70bd132edc64f1dd7ea4 I don't see tthe chart. Getting a `ProgressEvent` error. I am absolutely new to this and seeking for your help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695967/d3-js-ordinal-scale-version-3-to-version-4 for the answer